# PreparedStatement executeBatch with instead of insert trigger

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

We have a table with INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger. For the sake of simplicity, the trigger copy values to another table, and adds a timestampt to see if the trigger ran exactly only once (this is a mandatory condition).
We would like to insert thousands of rows (5-10) and ran the trigger only once.
The problem, I ran into, that even if I set autocommit off, and use executeBatch,the trigger runs multiple times.
Here is the Java code for the save:

```
  @Transactional
  public void saveMultiInserBatch(List<BulkImport> importThis) throws SQLException {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder("insert into interface.ui_test (description) values(?)");
    datasource.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
    PreparedStatement ps = datasource.getConnection().prepareStatement(build.toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < importThis.size(); i++) {
      ps.setString(1, importThis.get(i).getDescription());
      ps.addBatch();
    }
    ps.executeBatch();
    datasource.getConnection().commit();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Insert time was: " + (end - start));
  }
```

The values in the table after the insert, where the trigger inserts values:

```
    Multi Insert Batch0 2018-06-13 04:02:05.0424486
    Multi Insert Batch1 2018-06-13 04:02:05.1049570
    Multi Insert Batch2 2018-06-13 04:02:05.3705852
    Multi Insert Batch3 2018-06-13 04:02:05.3861983
    Multi Insert Batch4 2018-06-13 04:02:05.3861983
    Multi Insert Batch5 2018-06-13 04:02:05.3861983
    Multi Insert Batch6 2018-06-13 04:02:05.3861983
    Multi Insert Batch7 2018-06-13 04:02:05.3861983
    Multi Insert Batch8 2018-06-13 04:02:05.3861983
    Multi Insert Batch9 2018-06-13 04:02:05.3861983
    ...
```

As you can see from the timestamps the trigger ran multiple times.
What could cause this?

Comment: Why do you assume it would only fire the trigger once?

Comment: Is there any reason as to why you think this trigger would fire just once for multiple inserts?

Comment: I thought off, if I turn off the autocommit, and call the commit after execute.